# Swift function with Void return type versus no return type

Tags: swift, function, return-type

I'm struggling with understanding return values in Swift.
Can you explain the difference between these?

```
func someFunc() -> Void {}
func someFunc() {}
```

Comment: So there is no difference in return value itself, but difference in method signature (type) still persists?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Simply, there is no difference. `-> Void` is just an explicit way of saying that the function returns no value.

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID160):

> Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type **Void**. This is simply an empty tuple, in effect a tuple with zero elements, which can be written as **()**.

Thus, these three function declarations below are same:

```
func someFunc() {}
func someFunc() -> Void {}
func someFunc() -> () {}
```

Comment: I like explicit, because it makes me feel comfortable to see that there is nothing returned behind my back :D

Answer (score 4):

It's just some internal Swift inconsistency. Both definitions define the same, but:

```
func a() -> () {}
func b() {}          //by  default has same signature as a
func c() -> Void {}  //has different signature than a && b
```

so:

```
var x:(() -> Void) = c //OK
var y:(() -> ()) = a //OK
var z:(() -> ()) = c //ERROR - different signatures even if they mean the same
x = a //ERROR - different signatures, can't convert "() -> Void" into "() -> ()"
```

Comment: It seems, you missed the function body in `func c() -> Void`, should be `func c() -> Void {}`